# Displaying details of object arrays

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Hi I'm very new to programming and I'm trying to write a programme in eclipse that does the following.

- Create a Student class with 4 attributes: name, mark, course and phone number which are entered by the user.
- Have a constructor which initialises those four attributes to the parameters passed in, and a display() method which displays the details of the Student.
- Declares an empty array of 5 Student objects.
- Create a Student object at the current position of the array using these variables.
- Make a loop which calls the display() method of each Student in the array.

So far I've got the programme working to the point that it creates the array of 5 students and reads in the four different attributes from the user. But I can not figure out how to create a loop which calls the display method for each of the students.
This is my code so far..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student {


    private String name, course;
    private int mark, number;


    public Student(String nameIn, String courseIn, int markIn, int numberIn)
    {
        this.name = nameIn;
        this.course = courseIn;
        this.mark = markIn;
        this.number = numberIn;
    }


    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + this.name + " Course " + this.course + " mark: " + this.mark + " Number " + this.number);

    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

        String[] Student = new String[5];


        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);




        for (int counter=0; counter< 5; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter name for student " + counter);
            Student[counter] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter course for student " + counter);
            Student[counter] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter mark for student " + counter);
            Student[counter] = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter number for student " + counter);
            Student[counter] = scanner.nextLine();

        }
        for (int counter=0; counter< 5; counter++)
        {
            System.out.println(Student[counter].display());

        }
  }
}
```

PS sorry in advance if I have posted this question wrong. Its my first post and I couldn't find a similar question else where.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code doesn't create an array of `Student`, nor populate it correctly (each loop overwrites the former data) .

Also, the way you were calling `display` was wrong :

```
System.out.println(Student[counter].display());
```

First, you want to call `display` on an instance of `Student`, not on the class.
Second, you don't have to call `System.out.println`, because `display`already does this work (and calling `System.out.println` with the `void` parameter, because the `display` method returns nothing, will get you nowhere)

Try this way :

```
Student[] students = new Student[5];

for (int counter=0; counter< 5; counter++)
        {

            System.out.println("Enter name for student " + counter);
            String name = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter course for student " + counter);
            String course = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter mark for student " + counter);
            String mark = scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter number for student " + counter);
            String number = scanner.nextLine();

            Student student = new Student(name, course, mark, number);

            students[counter] = student;

        }

for (int counter=0; counter< students.length; counter++)
        {
           students[counter].display();

        }
```

Comment: While you're right, you're also not addressing his problem.  He's asking how to display the information pertaining to each student.  We should probably answer his question as best as possible without handing him a working solution, don't you think?  Any problems he encounters as a result of errors in his program are his to learn from, not ours to fix on his behalf.